# How do I create a column which has the value of the last time a condition was met in a separate row in R

Tags: r, position, sequence

I have data that looks like this:

```
d <- data.frame(Item = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

I would like to create a column where the value is based on the last time a 0 was present in the row d$item. I don't really know how to get started with something like this in R.

Expected outcome is this:

```
f$recent <- c(NA, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0)
```

Where each row is the the most recent observation of 0 (0 = on same row, 1 = previous row, etc.)

edit: Changed row to column, was posting before coffee. Also added expected result.

Comment: Do you mean column or variable instead of row?

Comment: Can you show the desired output?

Comment: Better provide an example for the expected output.

Comment: Edited for clarity

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, with `sequence`. It calculate the distance to the latest 1.

```r
dif <- diff(c(which(d$Item == 1), length(d$Item) + 1))
sequence(dif, 0)
#[1] 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Edit:

```r
dif <- diff(c(1, which(d$Item != 1), length(d$Item) + 1))
sequence(dif, 0)
#[1] 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 1 0 1 2 3 0
```

Comment: Nice answer if this is the thing the OP is after. Another option might be `with(rle(Item), sequence(lengths)) * (Item == 0)`

Comment: What's `lengths`?

Comment: `rle$lengths`, check `?with`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding your answer is very clean as well! I like the `* (Item == 0)` part

Answer (score 1):

You can try `rle` + `sequence`

```
transform(
  d,
  recent = with(rle(Item), sequence(lengths)) * (Item != 0)
)
```

which gives

```
   Item recent
1     1      1
2     0      0
3     0      0
4     1      1
5     1      2
6     1      3
7     1      4
8     1      5
9     1      6
10    0      0
11    0      0
12    1      1
13    0      0
14    1      1
15    1      2
16    1      3
17    0      0
```

Comment: This isn't quite it. The rows 5:9 should be increasing in value as it is increased rows since a 0 was observed.